# In Excel, I need one column to automatically populate if any cells in a range contain any text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this spreadsheet I am working on trying to automate a little bit. In the attached picture, I want to auto populate Column D if Columns E-I have some text in it. I need it to populate if any of them have text in it, not necessarily all of them.

This speadsheet is used for updating text on a website. The changes only get made once a month, so I use this sheet to hold the changes until then. When it's time to make changes, I want to filter column D on "Yes" (or whatever value) to easily see which categories need changed instead of just slowly going through the list. I know I can do this by hand, which I have been for months, but I would like to just have the "yes" automatically get added if I add text to any of the other cells within that row (E-I)

In Psuedo-code, looking at row 2 I want:

```
IF( E2 not empty OR F2 not Empty OR G2 Not empty OR H2 Not Empty OR I2 Not Empty )
THEN (D2 = "Yes")
```

Is this even possible?

I tried using an `=IF(ISTEXT(E2), "Yes", "")` which is the result I want, but I want it for a range of cells, not just one.

I tried `=IF(ISTEXT(E2:I2), "Yes", "")` and just flat out doesn't work. Causes a circular reference.

I tried `=IFS(ISTEXT(E2), "Yes", "", ISTEXT(F2), "Yes", "" ...etc)` and that works if E2 has text, but it will always show "#value", so I think I am doing something wrong with this one.

I know this is something minor, but I Would like to automate as much as I can with this.

[image]

Comment: Something like `=IF(LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,E2:I2)),"Yes","No")` Though the circular reference is odd: are there any formulas in E2:I2?

Comment: or `=IF(SUM(LEN(E2:I2)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: Thank you @DS_London! `=IF(SUM(LEN(E2:I2)), "YES", "NO")` worked perfectly for me! To answer your question, I had nothing in E2:I2, I don't get why I got that circular reference either.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DS_London :

`=IF(SUM(LEN(E2:I2)), "Yes", "")` was exactly what I needed to solve the problem!

Thank you!